# not sure if I should search or sort my hashmap

Tags: java, search, sorting, hashmap

Hi I have a list of people with their ages, I need to find those who are more than 30 years old, 
is there any possibility to search in a hashmap ? (please note that I may need to look for those in other age ranges as well so I prefer not to use two different lists for the sake of simplicity of code)

**In short: My goal is to find a way to search for elements with specific values in HashMap**

Sample list is

```
element1 40
element2 4
element3 66
element4 5
```

I want to find those with values more than 40 and those with values more than or equal to 66.

Comment: Are you using an ArrayList or a HashMap? Are you trying to search, select or sort? What do you mean by `it does not work`?

Comment: What do you mean “does not work”? The code you’ve shown should work.

Comment: Once you have the list sorted you can use a binary search to find a specific age.  But if you attempt to add the people back into your HashMap the order will be lost.  And if you only need to do this once, @assylias's comment is correct -- it's far less effort (and more straight-forward) to simply iterate over the list and select those over 30.

Comment: ... I assumed this was the intention of the question in my answer (before sort the array, than put in a Map for some other reason)...so if you definitely want to use a Map then could take into account a LinkedHashMap to maintain the insertion order...

Comment: whats structure of people map ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest you to use [NavigableMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html) (Implemented as TreeSet).

This implementation is a quite fast - O(log(N)), versus O(N) if you implement index based on lists.

Edit. Example:

```
class PersonsAgeIndex {

    private NavigableMap<Integer, List<Person>> ageToPersons = 
                                    new TreeMap<Integer, List<Person>>();

    public void addPerson( Person p ) {
        List<Person> personsWithSameAge = this.ageToPersons.get( p.age );

        if ( personsWithSameAge == null ) {
            personsWithSameAge = new LinkedList<Person>();
            this.ageToPersons.put( p.age, personsWithSameAge );
        }

        personsWithSameAge.add( p );
    }

    public List<Person> personsWithAgeLessThan( int age ) {
        List<Person> persons = new LinkedList<Person>();

        // persons with less age
        for (List<Person> tmp : this.ageToPersons.headMap( age ).values()) {
            persons.addAll( tmp );
        }

        return persons;
    }

    public List<Person> personsWithAgeInInterval( int minAge, int maxAge ) {
        List<Person> persons = new LinkedList<Person>();

        // persons with age, which: (minAge <= age <= maxAge)
        for (List<Person> tmp : this.ageToPersons.subMap( minAge, true, maxAge, true ).values()) {
            persons.addAll( tmp );
        }

        return persons;
    }

}

class Person {
    public final int age;

    public Person(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

Comment: @stemm, thanks for your answer but I would suggest not to use different lists because I have some other requirements that I should not have them in two different lists, for example I may need to have those more than 10 in this case I need to have another list for those items.

Comment: @Eme Emertana, There are lots of methods in NavigableSet interface, and method `tailMap` will solve the case 'age is greather than 10'. And method `subMap` will solve other cases. Also, you may use personsIndex independently from total list of persons. It's common practice of `indexes` usage

Comment: @stemm, does that mean I should use NavigableMap or TreeSet?

Comment: @Eme Emertana, I've added method `personsWithAgeInInterval` which covers all of your cases.

Comment: @Eme Emertana, Make your classes interface-dependent (e.g. `NavigableSet`) is better than specific-implementations-dependent (`TreeSet`) - it is one of concepts of flexible design. Look at my code above. For example, if you're want to make `PersonsAgeIndex` concurrency-oriented, all you have to do - just change `new TreeMap` to `new ConcurrentSkipListMap`. P.S. read the javadoc thoughtfully http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html - there is lots of useful information

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 private List<Person> getPeople(Map<?, Person> peopleMap, int filterAge) {
    List<Person> returnList = new ArrayList<Person>(peopleMap.values().size());
    for (Person p : peopleMap.values()) {
        if (p.getAge() > filterAge)
        returnList.add(p);
    }
    return returnList;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`HashMap`iteration order is 'not predictable' (that's to say that if you sort, and than insert keys, in a determinate order when you later try to iterate the keys the order is not the same).

Use a `LinkedHashMap` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Good question... unfortunately, a Map needs a very specific key.  Your solution above is the only real way to do it.

Alternatively you could maintain two lists, and store those that older than 30 to the 2nd list.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot sort a `HashMap`, it has no order. If you want an ordered `HashMap`, use `LinkedHashMap`.

Comment: Comments on downvote? Looks like some childish rager, doesn't it, opc0de ;)

Comment: I did not downvote but how is your answer helpful? Only changing the map implementation from hashmap to linkedhashmap will not solve the issue.

Comment: Yes it does because then he can sort it as he comments on the question. Not that I agree with such a method, but it would work :)

Answer (score 0):

```
HashMap<String,String> hmap = new HashMap<String,String>();
SortedSet<String> keys = new TreeSet<String>(hmap.keySet());
```

This will give you a sorted set which you could make a subset of.

keys.subSet(from,to) e.g  keys.subSet(30,100)

and you will have a set with all required elemets.

Comment: In your scenario 2 people can't have the same age.