# how to look for an element in HashMap

Tags: java, search, hashmap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [not sure if I should search or sort my hashmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12707769/not-sure-if-i-should-search-or-sort-my-hashmap)

Hi I have a list of people with their ages, I need to find those who are more than 30 years old, 
is there any possibility to search in a hashmap ? (please note that I may need to look for those in other age ranges as well so I prefer not to use two different lists for the sake of simplicity of code)

In short: My goal is to find a way to search for elements with specific values in HashMap

Sample list is

```
element1 40
element2 4
element3 66
element4 5
```

I want to find those with values more than 40 and those with values more than or equal to 66.

Is there any other way than iterating through all values?

Answer (score 2):

A `HashMap` provides a search by key only, so you will have to iterate the entire collection and filter the elements you don't want.

You can do it with a for each loop:

```
for (Entry<MyKey,MyValue> e : map.entrySet()) { 
    if (e.getValue() >= 40) { ....} //e.getKey() is an element with the needed value
    if (e.getValue() >= 66) { ... }
}
```

An alternative is holding a [`NavigableMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html) that maps from values to the elements that are relevant to them and use [`NavigableMap.subMap()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html#subMap%28K,%20K%29) (note if you might have dupe values, the value of the `NavigableMap` should be a `List`)

Comment: Google Guava have an open issue for a NavigableMultiMap :(

Answer (score 1):

With Guava you could do the following

```
import com.google.common.base.Predicate;
import com.google.common.collect.Maps;

public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        map.put("element1", 40);
        map.put("element2", 4);
        map.put("element3", 66);
        map.put("element4", 5);
        Map<String, Integer> filteredMap = Maps.filterValues(map,
                Predicates.equalTo(66));
    }
```

Since your required age may change you could have an AgePredicate that is used for the filtering

```
class AgePredicate implements Predicate<Integer> {
    int minAge;

    public AgePredicate(int minAge) {
        super();
        this.minAge = minAge;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean apply(Integer age) {
        return age > minAge;
    }
}
```

and use it in your filter as follows

```
Map<String, Integer> filteredMap = Maps.filterValues(map,new AgePredicate(66));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can iterate through the key values like this :

```
   Iterator<String> it = hm.keySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()){
        String key = it.next();
        if (hm.get(key) >= 40) {
            // do some stuff...
        }
    }
```